# Flutter How can i check Battery Health

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to check device Battery Health using Flutter the plugin Battery and the documentation didn't give any in formation about battery health it only shows you the battery state charging or not and battery level but didn't give you the health I mean goog bad something like this and Thankyou.
https://pub.dev/packages/battery
and this package wasn't able to help me

Comment: might be helpful https://medium.com/flutter-community/provide-battery-level-in-flutter-1b69fc4e6b2d

Answer (score 1):

As other solutions are mostly discontinued, I figured I might post a new one.

From the link page: https://pub.dev/packages/battery_info

```
// Import package
import 'package:battery/battery_info.dart';
import 'package:battery_info/model/android_battery_info.dart';
import 'package:battery_info/enums/charging_status.dart';
import 'package:battery_info/model/iso_battery_info.dart';

// Access current battery health - Android
print("Battery Health: ${(await BatteryInfoPlugin().androidBatteryInfo).health}");

// Access current battery level - IOS
print("Battery Level: ${(await BatteryInfoPlugin().iosBatteryInfo).batteryLevel}");

// Calculate estimated charging time
BatteryInfoPlugin().androidBatteryInfoStream.listen((AndroidBatteryInfo batteryInfo) {
  print("Charge time remaining: ${(batteryInfo.chargeTimeRemaining / 1000 / 60).truncate()} minutes");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Instantiate it
var battery = Battery();

// Access current battery level
var batteryPercentage = await battery.batteryLevel;
```

[you can refer this plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/battery)

Comment: this package ddin' give the battery health

Answer (score 0):

I am still searching for ios devices but there is a flutter package for android devices to get the battery health

```
import 'package:android_device_info/android_device_info.dart';
var batteryInfo = await AndroidDeviceInfo().getBatteryInfo();
print(batteryInfo);
```

Refer to the pub.dev link: [android_device_info](https://pub.dev/packages/android_device_info)

Answer (score 0):

You can try out https://pub.dev/packages/battery_info, it provides more detailed information on battery such as health, charging status, remaining charge time. However, there are some limitations on IOS due to Apple restrictions, so you can only get battery percentage and status on Apple devices.

You can also subscribe to a stream instead of just fetching future, so you could get life update on remaining charge time for example.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple dude.

Just Try this: https://pub.dev/packages/battery_info

It provides all information on the battery including its health, charging status, remaining charge time, etc. However, there are few limitations on IOS due to Apple restrictions, so you can only get battery percentage and status on Apple devices.